# Go to previous state in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm building a component which proceeds according to the selections of the users. I have completed it successfully but facing some issues when trying to implement a back button to go back.

My code is like follows.

```
class ReportMainCat extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {

            postType: null,

        }

        this.changeType = this.changeType.bind(this);
        this.report_next = this.report_next.bind(this);

    };

    report_next() {

        if (this.state.postType == null) {

            return <ReportFirst changeType={this.changeType}/>
        }

        else if (this.state.postType === 'sexual') {

            return <ReportXContent changeType={this.changeType}/>

        } else if (this.state.postType === 'selfharm') {

            return <ReportThreatContent changeType={this.changeType}/>

        } 

    }

    changeType = (postType) => {

        this.setState({postType})

        this.setState({

            showMainReportCats: false,

        })

    }

    render() {

        return (

            <div className="top_of_overlay">

                <div className="section_container text_align_center padding_10px">

                    <a className="">Report Category</a>

                    {this.report_next()}

                </div>

            </div>

        )

    }
}
```

I'm binding the `postType` value as follows.

```
class ReportXContent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {

            postType: '',

        }

    };

    textType(postType) {

        this.props.changeType(postType);

    }

    render() {

        return (

            <div className="text_align_left">

                <div>
                    <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                        <input type="checkbox" ref="nudity" onClick={this.textType.bind(this,'nudity')}/>
                        <a>Nudity or Pornography</a>
                    </div>

                    <div className="width_100 margin_bottom10px">
                        <input type="checkbox" ref="minor" onClick={this.textType.bind(this,'minor')}/>
                        <a>Includes Minors</a>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <ReportButtons/>

            </div>

        )

    }
}
```

My back button

```
<div>
<button className="float_right margin_left5px" onClick={this.props.back_report}>Back</button>
</div>
```

So basically what i'm trying to do is this.

Ex: If the user selects `postType` as `sexual` it will return the `ReportXContent` component. How can i return to the first page when the user clicks the back button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement the back button click handler like this in the `ReportMainCat` component:

```
handleBackClick() {
  this.setState({ postType: null });
}
```

, and that would show the `ReportFirst` view again.

If you don't want the *first* view, but the *last* view, simply change your `changeType` implementation to save `lastPostType` to state like this:

```
changeType = (postType) => {
  this.setState({ 
    lastPostType: this.state.postType,
    postType,
    showMainReportCats: false, 
  });
}
```

**Edit**

If you want full history of changes - let's say if you want to implement a full back button history - you can simply rename `lastPostType` to `postTypeHistory` and implement it like a stack (like the browser history is):

```
changeType = (postType) => {
  this.setState({ 
    postTypeHistory: [...this.state.postTypeHistory, this.state.postType],
    postType,
    showMainReportCats: false, 
  });
}

handleBackClick() {
  const { postTypeHistory } = this.state;
  const postType = postTypeHistory.pop();
  this.setState({
    postType,
    postTypeHistory,
  });
}
```

Comment: yes ur answer is awesome.. one issue though.. when saving the lastPostType i can save only one state. So i can go back only one step. How can i fix it?

Comment: Added another example that details that approach :)